# UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource methods not called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm working with `UITableViewCell` that has a `UICollectionView` inside. Everything works perfectly using this structure:

```
class PostCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {}
```

However, when I start to extract the UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource to another class

```
class PostCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    public func populate(users: [User]) {
        UsersManager(users: users, collectionView: collectionView)
    }
}
public class UsersManager: NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    private var users: [User]!
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    init(users: [User], collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        super.init()

        let nib = UINib(nibName: UserCell.IDENTIFIER, bundle:nil)
        collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: UserCell.IDENTIFIER)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

The delegate methods are not called.

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
```

I'm passing the collectionView to `UsersManager()`.
I'm calling both:

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
```

in the `UsersManager()`

What do you think is the problem here?

Comment: where are you creating instance UsersManager? you should have instance  of UsersManager

Comment: Updated my @karthikeyan. Thanks for helping. =D

Comment: I am suspecting NSObject Class its asking you Coder and decoder, check this link https://github.com/macelangelo/HorizontalCollectionViews
your goal achieved same way by using UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PostCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var usersManager:UsersManager?  // add this line.

    public func populate(users: [User]) {
        usersManager = UsersManager(users: users, collectionView: collectionView)
    }
}
```